# Compiling Objective-C code on mac terminal

Tags: objective-c

I have just started learning Objective-C and I am stuck on a very simple issue. I have written a small program and trying to compile it through Mac terminal by using following command:

```
clang -framework Foundation main.m -o prog
```

It was working fine until I wrote the following code in main.m

```
Calculator *calculator = [[Calculator alloc]initWithExpression:expressionArray];
```

It has started giving me following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Calculator", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main-a39d3a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How to tell compiler to import calculator.h file although I have included the following line in main.m:

```
#import "Calculator.h"
```

Comment: Do you also have a 'calculator.m' file?

Comment: You need to include `Calculator.m` on the compile line so it gets linked with `main.m`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a file 'Calculator.m' in your sources, your compile command must look like

```
clang -framework Foundation Calculator.m main.m -o prog
```